# backspace active li class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem with some jquery and http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history_noc.html

The function works great, my problem is to highlight an li class, tab menu, when user backspace with the keyboard or just use the back button on their browser to return the last seen page.

**html code**

li code with the class active, when page is on

```
<li class="active"><a href="#prices" rel="history"><span>Prices</span></a></li>
```

**jquery code:**

This is loaded when

```
$(document).ready 
    $('li > a').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
});
```

Can i make som .... keyCode == 8 (backspace key) to return last page ? 
Can somebody give me a tip, or mabye give me an code example :-/

Comment: Using FF3.0.13/Ubuntu 8.04, using the backspace key already does what I think you're asking. Similarly the shift+backspace moves forward in the history.

Comment: what ? I'm not sure i understand what you are trying to say? :/

Comment: ricebowl is saying that using the backspace key already does what you're asking, "when user backspace with the keyboard or just use the back button on their browser to return the last seen page". I tested here in my machine (Vista x64, Firefox 3.5.2 and IE8) and it works as well. Could you explain a little more what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider storing the state in a cookie (whether or not a class has been added to an element, for instance), and re-initializing your page from the values written to the cookie within your `$(document).ready` function. I did something similar to keep expandy bits of the page expanded. Check out the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie).

Comment: this look very useful, can you give an example ?